# SQL Server Conditional Mailing Address Formatting

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL to format a US address into each line for a mailing address but it is rather ugly. Is there a better way to solve this problem or does it have to be this ugly? Also, the problem with this code is that it always ends up with an extra new line at the end.

```
declare @NL varchar(2);
set @NL = char(13) + char(10);

select 
  case when rtrim(coalesce(AttentionLine,'') ) != '' then rtrim(AttentionLine ) + @NL else '' end
  + case when rtrim(coalesce(Recipient,'') ) != '' then rtrim(Recipient ) + @NL else '' end
  + case when rtrim(coalesce(AddlAddrLine,'') ) != '' then rtrim(AddlAddrLine ) + @NL else '' end
  + case when rtrim(coalesce(DeliveryAddr,'') ) != '' then rtrim(DeliveryAddr ) + @NL else '' end
  + case when rtrim(coalesce(LastLine,'') ) != '' then rtrim(LastLine ) + @NL else '' end
  + case when rtrim(coalesce(Country,'') ) != '' then rtrim(Country ) + @NL else '' end
as FormattedMailingAddress    
from Address 
where Id = 1
```

Comment: This is a typical example why data formatting should, *when possible and practical*, be done on the client-side rather than as part of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize this is an old question, but there is a new solution to this problem: the [CONCAT_WS()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-ws-transact-sql) function, which is new for SQL Server 2017 (it's also available for Azure SQL Database).

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS (
    CHAR(13) + CHAR(10),    --Separator
    NULLIF(AttentionLine, ''),
    NULLIF(Recipient, ''),
    NULLIF(AddlAddrLine, ''),
    NULLIF(DeliveryAddr, ''),
    NULLIF(LastLine, ''),
    NULLIF(Country, '')
)
AS FormattedMailingAddress    
FROM Address 
WHERE Id = 1
```

`NULL` values are ignored by the function, which is why `NULLIF` is used with each argument/parameter in this example. (When the argument/parameter evaluates to `NULL`, the separator won't be added either). Here's a short blog post with some more details: [New For SQL Server 2017: T-SQL Function CONCAT_WS](https://itsalljustelectrons.blogspot.com/2018/03/New-For-SQL-Server-2017-TSQL-Function-CONCATWS.html)

Answer (score 3):

If your Sql Server Settings are such that NULL + varchar returns NULL ([SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176056.aspx)), this can help.

```
DECLARE @Address TABLE(
        ID INT,
        AttentionLine VARCHAR(50),
        Recipient VARCHAR(50),
        AddlAddrLine VARCHAR(50),
        DeliveryAddr VARCHAR(50),
        LastLine VARCHAR(50),
        Country VARCHAR(50)
)

declare @NL varchar(2); 
set @NL = char(13) + char(10); 

INSERT INTO @Address SELECT 1, NULL, '1', NULL, '2', NULL, '3'

select  
  case when rtrim(coalesce(AttentionLine,'') ) != '' then rtrim(AttentionLine ) + @NL else '' end 
  + case when rtrim(coalesce(Recipient,'') ) != '' then rtrim(Recipient ) + @NL else '' end 
  + case when rtrim(coalesce(AddlAddrLine,'') ) != '' then rtrim(AddlAddrLine ) + @NL else '' end 
  + case when rtrim(coalesce(DeliveryAddr,'') ) != '' then rtrim(DeliveryAddr ) + @NL else '' end 
  + case when rtrim(coalesce(LastLine,'') ) != '' then rtrim(LastLine ) + @NL else '' end 
  + case when rtrim(coalesce(Country,'') ) != '' then rtrim(Country ) + @NL else '' end 
as FormattedMailingAddress     ,
    RTRIM(coalesce(AttentionLine + @NL,'')) + 
    RTRIM(coalesce(Recipient + @NL,'')) + 
    RTRIM(coalesce(AddlAddrLine + @NL,'')) + 
    RTRIM(coalesce(DeliveryAddr + @NL,'')) + 
    RTRIM(coalesce(LastLine + @NL,'')) + 
    RTRIM(coalesce(Country + @NL,'')) 
from @Address  
where Id = 1
```

Comment: That was originally what I was thinking too... unfortunately sometimes the fields are also empty strings, which messed things up

Comment: @RobPackwood You can use NULLIF() to turn empty strings into NULLs, too.

Comment: +1 for the cool NULLIF() keyword. Our data is so inconsistent that we sometimes have fields that are blank with spaces in them. The NULLIF() would still require 2 RTRIM() calls per field but is a nifty way to avoid the CASE statement in my original post.

Comment: @astander I will mark this answer as the accepted one if I do not hear back from anyone else in the next hour. I think you have a good answer here barring our own internal data consistency issues.

Comment: @RobPackwood Yes I know a little late to the game here, but for other's benefit, I often use: **case when len(isnull(AttentionLine,'')) > 0**.  With this syntax, even spaces return a len value of zero.